# Appscript not working in shared person id

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet, file-sharing

I have a Google sheet. I have made appscript in it and working fine on my id but not working on the id of person to whom I shared it.
I don't know why it happened

I have changed the protection cells fully and tried to reload page but not working.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.